# Using Output from Function 1 as Input in Function 2

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions

so I have some code like the following:

```
def _step_1(a, b, c):
    some codes
    return d, e, f

def _step_2(d, e, f, a, b):
    some codes
    return g

def _run_all(a, b, c):
    g = _step_2(_step_1(a, b, c), a, b)
    return g
```

And it is telling me that I am missing two arguments "a" and "b". Could someone tell me if I did anything wrong by trying to save some steps? Or there is no way to save steps? I know I can definitely write like this:

```
def _run_all(a, b, c):
    d, e, f = _step_1(a, b, c)
    g = _step_2(d, e, f, a, b)
    return g
```

Comment: You're only passing three arguments to `_step_2()`.  Even though the result of `_step_1(a,b,c)` _contains_ three elements, it is itself just a tuple.  As @U9-Forward answered, if you're using Python 3, you can automatically unpack that result into its three separate values.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! And yes, I am using Python 3, it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your version is python 3, use unpacking (`*`):

```
def _run_all(a, b, c):
  g = _step_2(*_step_1(a, b, c), a, b)
  return g
```